# List of open source tools to automate Oracle form (desktop based) application?

Tags: automated-testing, desktop-application

Can anybody guide me, how I can automate oracle form (desktop based) application? Prefer the name of open source tools.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Oracle Forms applications are based on Java. I know of some who are using [Marathon](https://sourceforge.net/projects/marathonman) to automate oracle forms applications.

Comment: Thanks for it. Can you please send more details because on Marathon tools site I not seen any information regarding it.